# I can't seem to get my nullable datetime formatted to "yyyy-mm-dd" using C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, format, tostring

I am trying to generate an XML file and it works with my date straight out of database table. "mm-dd-yyyy".
However I can't seem to format it to reverse for the required "yyyy-mm-dd".

I keep getting told "No overload for method 'ToString()' takes 1 arguments".

It doesn't work inside the "new XElement" or before it:

```
XElement samplecollectionenddate = new XElement(EN + "SampleCollectionEndDate", samp.SampDate.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd"));
```

I've looked all over StackOverflow and I see all these wonderful string formats but I can't put anything inside my .ToString() parenthesis.

Here is the IEnumerable that I fill with samps.

```
IEnumerable<EDI_RAW_TCR> samples = from c in dc.EDI_RAW_TCRs
       where c.Batch_ID == 20830
       where c.LabID == raw.LabID
       orderby c.Raw_ID
       select c;

foreach (EDI_RAW_TCR samp in samples)
{
```

Just in case I am missing a library, here is the top of my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;
```

Comment: samp.SampDate.ToString("yyyy'-'mm'-'dd"));

Comment: If I put the cursor over the samp.SampDate I get a DateTime? with a question mark. Lucky my friend was still here at work and said he has had the same problem and gave me this code that worked. I am making it my answer only because I think someone else might be able to use it.
            string dt = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", samp.SampDate);

         XElement samplecollectionenddate =   new XElement(EN + "SampleCollectionEndDate", dt);

Comment: mohsen, that sure looks nice to me but the ToSTring() wouldn't allow anything in the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nullable type can represent the correct range of values for its underlying value type, plus an additional null value.

```
if( samp.SampDate != null )    
{
    XElement samplecollectionenddate = new XElement(EN + "SampleCollectionEndDate", samp.SampDate.Value.ToString("yyyy'-'mm'-'dd")); 
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: I am positive there will be no nulls in my application, but your answer adds to concept and is important. So I selected this as the answer. Also, I think this is why the "ToString()" would not accept any parameters: If it was a "Not Null" field/datatype, it would have allowed parameters inside the "ToString()".

Answer (score 1):

Here is what appears to work.

```
string dt = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", samp.SampDate);

XElement samplecollectionenddate = new XElement(EN + "SampleCollectionEndDate", dt);
```